# What is the correct way to put a frame in a bootstrap modal?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to put a frame in a css modal, but the way it is being displayed is not the most pleasant, and besides, as I did the adjustment (top and left) manually, for other screen sizes the image is misconfigured (frame outside the modal). As per the image below.

On big screen

[image: On big screen]

On small screen

[image: On small screen]

I used the following code to get the above results

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background: lightgray;
        }

        .frame-card {
            width: 800px;
            height: 520px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            left: 31.2%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-2">
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary video-btn" data-toggle="modal"
            data-src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/58385453?badge=0&autoplay=1&loop=1" data-target="#myModal">
            Play Vimeo Video
        </button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video" allowscriptaccess="always"
                                allow="autoplay">
                            </iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img class="frame-card" src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/004/266/329/original/frame-card.png?1671470988">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Gets the video src from the data-src on each button
            var $videoSrc;
            $('.video-btn').click(function () {
                $videoSrc = $(this).data("src");
            });
            // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
            $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
                $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc);
            })
            // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
            $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                // a poor man's stop video
                $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc);
            })
            // document ready  
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What classes or styling should I use?

Thanks in advance!

I used position property with absolute value to align the image, I don't know if it's the right approach to do, besides, I used left and top alignment, I would like a more "automatic" way to align the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about your desired result but, I have managed to put the frame neatly around the video. Move the `.frame-card` inside the `.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-16by9` right after the `iframe` and just give it `.embed-responsive-item` and no additional styles are necessary, as it will have the same size/position as the video (`iframe.embed-responsive-item`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Gets the video src from the data-src on each button
  var $videoSrc;
  $('.video-btn').click(function() {
    $videoSrc = $(this).data("src");
  });
  // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
    $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc);
  })
  // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
  $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
    // a poor man's stop video
    $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc);
  })
  // document ready  
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-2">
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/58385453?badge=0&autoplay=1&muted=1&loop=1" data-target="#myModal">
    Play Vimeo Video
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video" allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay">
            </iframe>
            <img class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/004/266/329/original/frame-card.png?1671470988">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

### Note:

You need to add `&muted=1` to your video source URL in order for autoplay to work: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplay-and-loop-embedded-videos The video doesn't work in the snippet but you can check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9tcgw2v/).